# procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name in Access-Vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I receive this message in vba, can someone analyse this question? I have to finish this work, however it's been shown difficult with this errors.

```
Private Sub ListTarefas_DblClick()
    Dim idtarefas As Integer
    Dim func As Integer
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    ShowEquipa

    Form_Projetos.List0.RowSource = ""
    idtarefas = ListTarefas.Column(0, ListTarefas.ListIndex)
    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Equipas  WHERE [ID-Tarefa] LIKE '" & idtarefa & "' " & _
    ";", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    With Form_Projetos
        .List0.RowSourceType = "Value List"

        Do Until rst.EOF
            func = rst.Fields("ID-Func").value
            .List0.AddItem (func)
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    rst.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an argument, not

```
 Private Sub ListTarefas_DblClick()
```

But

```
 Private Sub ListTarefas_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
```

The error message is typical for a missing argument.

I do not see why you are taking such a long way around when Access accepts an SQL statement as a row source.

Comment: I have another procedure Private Sub ListProjetos_DblClick() and I don't get error message.

Comment: Are you saying that I can put

idtarefas = ListTarefas.Column(0, ListTarefas.ListIndex)
Form_Projetos.List0.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Equipas  WHERE [ID-Tarefa] LIKE '" & idtarefa & "' " & _
    ";", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    With Form_Projetos

Comment: I am suggesting that you use a linked table and refer to that, Microsoft recommends linked tables for 2013.